# How do I make a jQuery UI accordion header box smaller?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a jQuery Accordion that is collapsed by default (`collapsible: true, active: false`) and it works great, but it is too big. I managed to change the size of the elements inside the open accordion, but I haven't been able to make the collapsed accordion smaller (the `h3` tag).

I tried giving the `h3` tag a class name and style that class with a smaller font-size with no effect, and tried to change the `h3` tag to a `h5` with no effect. I also tried adding the option 'header: "h5"' to the jQuery accordion call while having a `h5` tag as the header with no effect.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    $(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
});

<div id="accordion">
    <h3>@Resources.AccordionTitle</h3>
    <div>
        <form></form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include enough code in your question to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Inspect the css in browser dev tools (F12) and adjust accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Suchit's answer and after playing with the CSS a bit, this is what did what I was looking for:

Html:

```
<div id="MyAccordion">
    <h3>AccordionHeader</h3>
    <div>
        /*Accordion Content*/
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#MyAccordion .ui-accordion-header {  
line-height: 15px;   /*Header Box height*/
font-size: 13px;     /*Header Text size*/
text-indent: 10px;}  /*Not quite sure about this one*/
```

Script:

```
$(function () {
    $("#MyAccordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*If you are trying to change the font size of the accordion header Try adding this css to your accordion : this will make header text smaller but you can set the font of your desire by changing font-size.*

```
#accordion .ui-accordion-header {  
    line-height: 20px;   //reduces height of the header box
    font-size: 10pt;  
    width: 100%;  
    text-indent: 10px;  
}
```

***See the demo:***

```js
$(function() { 
$( "#accordion" ).accordion();
 $("#accordion .ui-accordion-content").css({ width:"260px" });// width of the box content area
});
```

```css
#accordion .ui-accordion-header {  
    line-height: 20px;   
    font-size: 10pt;  
    width: 100%;  
    text-indent: 10px;  
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
</script>

<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion" style="width:300px;">
<h3>Section 1</h3>
<div>
<p>
Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
ut neque. 
</p>
</div>
<h3>Section 2</h3>
<div>
<p>
Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
purus.
</p>
</div>
<h3>Section 3</h3>
<div>
<p>
Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. 
</p>
<ul>
<li>List item one</li>
<li>List item two</li>
<li>List item three</li>
</ul>
</div>
<h3>Section 4</h3>
<div>
<p>
Cras dictum. 
</p>
<p>
Suspendisse eu nisl.
</p>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does make the header text smaller (Thx for this part, one step closer to my goal)  but the header box stays the same (what I call the header box is the accordion collapsed), and also after this the content box does not align correctly with the header box, is that intended?

Comment: @Elound you want width to be reduced or height.

Comment: I just found out that you need to avoid setting a width for the content and the header box to be the exact same width. I'll post my code as an answer for you too look at it, even with both css set to width:100% the header was always larger the the content, with no width set at all the accordion works correctly.